# How can I run a node script from bash using cron

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, ubuntu, cron

I have this cron job running on Ubuntu

```
02 12 * * * quigley-user /mnt/block/alphabits/start.sh >> /mnt/block/alphabits/start.log
```

The cron job runs on schedule as expected.

I have this snippet in the start.sh script

```
while read -r ticker apiName ;
   do
      echo "$ticker $apiName"
      sudo /usr/bin/node /mnt/block/alphabits/index.js $ticker $apiName
   done < /mnt/block/alphabits/fmpList.txt
```

The echo line shows the expected results, however the index.js script does not run.  I can't find an error but maybe I'm missing something. If I run the command that's in the cron job from the command line it executes properly

What am I missing?  Thanks!

Comment: Is "quigley-user" in sudoers groups? If you want to see the entire output of the script including errors use `2>&1` like this: `02 12 * * * quigley-user /mnt/block/alphabits/start.sh >> /mnt/block/alphabits/start.log 2>&1`.

If I had to guess it could be related to "quigley-user" needing to write it's password to execute the command as sudo.

Comment: That did highlight the issue. thank you - 
It's this line, it seems from cron the env vars in app.env aren/'t found so for some reason I'm guessing the app.env file isn't found 
require('dotenv').config({ path: require('find-config')('app.env') });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible your `node.js` relative import path is missing from `crontab` context.

And possible other implicit environment variables configurations for `node.js`

Assuming your user `$HOME` directory is `/home/user1`

#### Suggesting:

Add the following line, into your 2nd line in your `start.sh`

```
  #!/bin/bash
  source /home/user1/.bash_profile
```

This line will add your users' context path and environment variables to your script.